# Pegar valor do Json com Node

Tags: node.js

Quero fazer um login em um site, utilizando Node. O login seria realizar um select no banco de dados, de acordo com o E-mail digitado, e então verificar se a senha está de acordo. 
No submit do login, realizo o select no banco de dados, e os dados do usuário são exibidos na página em formato JSON.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
var email = req.body.email;
var senha = req.body.senha;
senha = criptografar(senha);

execSQL("select * from Usuario where email = '"+ email+"' ", res);

if(senha == *senha recuperada do json*)
     logar();
});


function execSQL(sql, resposta) {
global.conexao.request()
.query(sql)
.then(resultado => resposta.json(resultado.recordset))
.catch(erro => resposta.json(erro));
}
```

O json exibido na página localhost:3000 é :

```
[{
  "codUsuario":100,
  "nome":"Pedro Pereira",
  "cpf":"042.321.123-22",
  "email":"pedropereira@gmail.com",
  "telefone":"(19)1212-3232",
  "senha":"112233",
  "peso":50,
  "altura":1,
  "codNutricionista":4999,
  "Pontuação":0
}]
```

Como pego a senha exibida na página?

Comment: Você precisa enviar a senha através do `request`, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa aguardar os dados do retorno da consulta e fazer a verificação da senha. Você pode fazer isso usando async/await. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```js
app.post('/login', async function(req, res){
 var email = req.body.email;
 var senha = req.body.senha;
 senha = criptografar(senha);
 
 var sqlQry1 = "select * from Usuario where email = '"+ email+"' ";
 let resultados = await global.conn.request().query(sqlQry1);
 resultados.recordset.forEach(function(item) {
  if(senha == item.senha){
   logar();
  }  
 }); 
});
```

Pelo exemplo do seu retorno, a senha não está criptografada. No seu código, você recebe a senha postada e executa uma função chamada criptografar. Se a senha é guardada sem criptografia, a comparação não vai funcionar.